# What would a better industry standard title be than "Team Captain" and "Team Leader"?

Tags: roles, organizational-structure

I recently took a position as a Team Captain. I report to my Team Leader who then reports out of department to an operations manager who manages multiple departments with hundreds of people. I handle almost all of the same tasks as he does without a few minor tasks. However, when he is ill or on vacation I assume the role entirely.

I find the term "team captain" a bit childish. From what I've been seeing online, the two words are used interchangeably. I feel his position should be "manager".

We decide everything together, and always consult each other, but I feel there is a large gap there between operations manager and team leader.  Team Captain reporting to a Team Leader I find confusing. If anything wouldn't the Team Captain be in charge? The Captain of the ship, while the Tr Lead (still being within the team and doing team duties, be the "right hand man"?  I need to make suggestions because I would like to use that title but also don't want to take away from his title or coworkers thinking I am lying or trying to over step.

What are industry standard job titles that would fit the situation I have described?

Comment: Hi Christopher1986, and welcome to PM:SE. Sadly this is not a discussion forum it is a Q&A site where questions are expected to have canonical answers. See the site Tour here for more information on the types of questions considered on-topic: pm.stackexchange.com/tour - If your question can be edited to ask specific questions it may be on-topic, but at present it is likely to be closed as an "opinion poll".

Comment: Hi Chris, I made an [edit] to address Marv and others concerns.  Questions more specific, with a clear goal, tend to work best on our Q&A site.  See [ask] for more details.  Hope the edits help get you a good solid answer.  If the community members vote to close, check out their suggestions in the comments for how you might further edit to clarify. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Christopher1986 - can you be more specific about what you actually do in your role? There are a lot of generalities in the description you provide, i.e. "we decide everything together", "need to make suggestions".

Comment: How about _Project Coordinator_?

Comment: "Thought Synergizer"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a industry standard for what you do.

But using your ship analogy with a captain I'd say, just as you pointed out, your Team Leader is essentially the Team Captain. That would make you the **First Mate** or **Team Mate**. He's the captain's "right-hand-man" and he also does everything the captain does if the captain isn't around.

Comment: "Kirk" and "Spock"?